# Memory usage grouped by parent process

Tags: linux, memory, process, centos-6

How can I find the total memory usage of all processes (including child processes) with `PPID` of 1. For a program like nginx/httpd which forks several child processes, `ps`/`top` gives the memory usage of each process separately. I want to know the total memory usage of `nginx`/`apache` instead of the individual child processes.

Answer (score 14):

If you want something interactive, try :

```
atop - launch it and press 'm' (memory usage) and 'p' (group by process name).
```

If you want something scriptable, there's something a bit like the below - although it's not doing quite what you've asked for (PPID 1), but you can group based on e.g. process name using awk -

```
ps -eo pmem,vsize,cmd | grep -v '\[' | awk 'NR>2{mem[$3]+=$2}END {for(k in mem) print k " " mem[k]/1024000};' | sort -gk 2 | tail -n 10
```

There's probably some clever way to filter on ppid with the ps... but I'm too stupid to figure it out quickly.

Comment: Also, pressing 'a' will show all processes, instead of just active ones.

Answer (score 1):

On a distro using systemd, [`systemd-cgls`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cgls.html) should show memory usage per service. Doesn't always obtain the information though.

Comment: Thanks. The server is running CentOS 6, so there is no systemd. I have added the `centos-6` tag to the question.